# UIBarButtonItem isn't shown in combination with large title inside navigation bar

Tags: swift, navigationbar

I want to show an UIBarButtonItem as the rightBarButtonItem in my navigation bar. To achieve this, I'm using the code below. Unfortunately it doesn't work.

```
private func configureBarButtons() {
    let upButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "arrow.up"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleUpButtonTapped))
    navigationController!.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = upButton
}
```

The method from above is called in `viewDidLoad()`.
Until now I haven't found an existing question which solves my problem here on SA...
Thanks for your help!
As it looks right now:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not set navigation item of NavigationController rather you should set the navigation item of your ViewController which has embedded `UINavigationController` to it.

So in your ViewController's `viewDidLoad` write

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let upButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "arrow.up"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleUpButtonTapped))
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = upButton
   }
```

Or in your case, simply write

```
private func configureBarButtons() {
    let upButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "arrow.up"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleUpButtonTapped))
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = upButton
}
```

Comment: @finebel: AM glad I could help :) Please consider accepting the answer if it helped :)